# How to debug a JDK docker container in intellij idea?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose

I want to start up a docker container with debug options as follows, but the startup won't work:

`Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-11 as dependencies
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY .dockerdev/settings.xml .
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
ENTRYPOINT["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 5005:5005
```

Result:

```
docker-compose up
Recreating my_app ... done
Attaching to my_app
app_1  | Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
app_1  | Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
app_1  | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
app_1  | [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ my_app ---
app_1  | [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
app_1  | [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
app_1  | [INFO] Copying 3 resources
app_1  | [INFO] Copying 3 resources
app_1  | [INFO] 
app_1  | [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ my_app ---
app_1  | [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
app_1  | [INFO] 
app_1  | [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ my_app ---
app_1  | [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
app_1  | [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
app_1  | [INFO] Copying 3 resources
app_1  | [INFO] 
app_1  | [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my_app ---
app_1  | [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
app_1  | [INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /opt/app/target/test-classes
app_1  | [INFO] 
app_1  | [INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.7:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ my_app <<<
app_1  | [INFO] 
app_1  | [INFO] 
app_1  | [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.7:run (default-cli) @ my_app ---
app_1  | [INFO] Attaching agents: []
app_1  | Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
app_1  | ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
app_1  | ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
app_1  | JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [./src/jdk.jdwp.agent/share/native/libjdwp/debugInit.c:735]
app_1  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
app_1  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | [INFO] Total time:  3.000 s
app_1  | [INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-23T12:30:50Z
app_1  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.7:run (default-cli) on project my_app: Application finished with exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
app_1  | [ERROR] 
app_1  | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
app_1  | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
app_1  | [ERROR] 
app_1  | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
app_1  | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
my_app exited with code 1
```

Sidenote: Port 5005 is of course *not* running/listening on my host!
Also, if I change the port to 5006, 5007 etc, the error is always the same.

So why is the port blocked on `mvn spring-boot:run`?

Comment: The problem is you are passing `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. Which will be used by Maven **and** Spring Boot. Maven will run with those options as well, opening the port for debugging Maven. Then a new proces will start Spring Boot in a forked JVM which will also pick up these settings and try to attach again. What you should do is pass properties in your ENTRYPOINT and specify `-Drun.jvmArguments=<remote-debug-here>` for the Spring Boot thing to work (and make sure maven doesn't detect those settings as well).

Comment: If I add the following into `Dockerfile`,  the `agentlib` statement seems not to be detected at all: `ENTRYPOINT["mvn", "spring-boot:run", "-Drun.jvmArguments=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005"]`

Comment: Apparently you should use `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments` and you have to take care of the quotes as well.

Comment: What do you mean by *quotes*? The following also does not succeed: `ENTRYPOINT["mvn", "spring-boot:run", "-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005"]`

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.debug... The jvmarguments need to be in quotes as well, so you probably need some `\"` in the string.

Comment: Unfortunately `ENTRYPOINT["mvn", "spring-boot:run", "-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=\"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005\""]` does not make a difference

Comment: Doesn't make a difference in what way? You also need to ditch the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` else you still have the same issue (as mentioned in my initial comment).

Comment: Yes I remove the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` completely. Sorry, with no difference I mean I can start the app, but the `agentlib` does not seem to be recognized. The logs are missing any agentlib infos, and 5005 is therefore missing inside the container.

Comment: Excuse, docker-compose was using some cached layer for the startup. Rebuilding the app with clean cache works as expected. Would you mind adding it as answer that the agentlib statement has to be placed into the `ENTRYPOINT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that there are 2 debug sessions being started. 1 for the maven command and 1 for the forked JVM voor Spring Boot. Hence the error and changing the port won't solve this as the problem will remain.

What you need to do is remove the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` from your docker compose file and instead add the following to your entry point

```
-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

That way it will only apply to the Spring Boot plugin and will be taken into account when launching the app in a new JVM.