# Port already in use with Docker-compose JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jmx

I was trying to connect JMX with docker locally but getting Port is already in use. I did change port numbers to different(which are not in use).
Anyone, please suggest what is wrong with my configuration.

`docker-compose.yml:`

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.build.yml
      service: mvn
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "1099:1099"
    environment:
      JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 \
       -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
       -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 \
       -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
       -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
    links:
      - activemq
    command: spring-boot:run
    env_file: .env
  activemq:
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
```

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
app_1       | Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
app_1       |   java.net.BindException: Address in use
app_1       | jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
app_1       |   java.net.BindException: Address in use
app_1       |   at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:492)
app_1       |   at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
app_1       |   at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
app_1       | Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is:
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I give credit to others, here is where I found an answer to this problem:

[How to debug a JDK docker container in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72348615/how-to-debug-a-jdk-docker-container-in-intellij-idea)

The maven command itself is stealing the debug port before spring can run and use it. The solution I needed for making this work with Google's Skaffold / Cloud Code is:

```
CMD JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="" ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
```

(If you're running this straight from a Docker compose, you won't need to export the blank environment variable.)